# IIS, application host and extensible application architecture

Tags: .net, iis, architecture, iis-7, extensibility

I have read about how to build extensible application architecture through Jeffery Richter's book < CLR via C# >. And I know that IIS is some kind of a "host application" which can host our web applications.

I have a vague impression that there's must be some key ***relationship*** between the following concepts:

- Host Application
- Application Domain
- Extensible application arthictecture

Could someone talk about the relationship of the above concepts in the context of IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will go some way to explaining:

- Host Application

  IIS is a host application, or rather an IIS Application Pool (w3wp.exe) is a host application. It's just a regular Windows Process.
- Application Domain

  Inside a the host application there is the concept of [Application Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx). A host application can contain one or more Application Domains. Application Domains can be thought of as "soft" processes providing .NET application isolation within a host process. For example if you have multiple websites all using the same Application Pool then each web application will have it's own Application Domain. Application Domains can be loaded and unloaded independently of others much like Windows processes.

  Take a look at Scott Forsyth's short training video:

  > [AppDomain - What it is and why it's important](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/03/19/asp-net-appdomain-what-it-is-and-why-it-s-important-part-12-of-52-part-series.aspx)
- Extensible Application Architecture

  An Extensible Application Architecture is one that provides hook or integration points so that you can extend the application in some way. IIS7 is one such application. IIS7 can be extended in many ways, for example, these are some of the many ways that IIS7 has been extended beyond the core installation:

  > http://www.iis.net/download

  Here's a good starting point for learning more about how to extend IIS7:

  > [Extending IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/22/extending-iis-70/)